# Bindings.createObjectBinding and null dependencies

Tags: java, javafx

I have `node` property that is `ObjectProperty<VBox>` and I want to have `nodeSize` property that depends on `node` property.

It will look like this:

```
public final class PropertyProblem {

    public PropertyProblem() {
        nodeSize.bind(initNodeSizeBinding(node));
    }

    private ObjectBinding<Dimension2D> initNodeSizeBinding(ObjectProperty<VBox> nodeProperty) {
        return Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
            if (nodeProperty.get() == null) {
                return null;
            }

            VBox node = nodeProperty.get();
            ReadOnlyDoubleProperty widthProperty = node.widthProperty(),
                    heightProperty = node.heightProperty();
            return new Dimension2D(widthProperty.get(), heightProperty.get());
        }, nodeProperty);
    }

    // node property
    private final ObjectProperty<VBox> node = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "node", null);

    public ObjectProperty<VBox> nodeProperty() {
        return node;
    }

    public void setNode(VBox val) {
        node.set(val);
    }

    public VBox getNode() {
        return node.get();
    }

    // nodeSize property
    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Dimension2D> nodeSize = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>
            (this, "nodeSize");

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Dimension2D> nodeSizeProperty() {
        return nodeSize;
    }

    public Dimension2D getNodeSize() {
        return nodeSize.get();
    }

}
```

Let's focus on `initNodeSizeBinding()` method.
The problem is I can't provide dependencies (node's width and height) for the binding, because obviously `node` property can be `null`. Is there any other way to cope with this without creation of binding every time the `node` property changes its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want [Bindings.when](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#when(javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue)), which is the dynamic binding equivalent of the tertiary operator (that is, *condition* `?` *trueExpr* `:` *falseExpr*​):

```
return Bindings
    .when(nodeProperty.isNotNull())
    .then(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
        () -> new Dimension2D(nodeProperty.get().getWidth(),
                              nodeProperty.get().getHeight()),
        Bindings.selectDouble(nodeProperty, "width"),
        Bindings.selectDouble(nodeProperty, "height"))
    .otherwise((Dimension2D) null);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `Bindings.selectDouble(nodeProperty.get(), "width")` instead of `Bindings.selectDouble(nodeProperty, "width")` and same with height?

Comment: @StackOverflow No, because you want the selected `width` property to always be from the `VBox` that''s in the `ObservableValue<VBox>` at any given moment, not just the `VBox` that's there when the method (to create the binding) is called.